# Power Adaptor Compatibility

Tags: power-supply, compatibility, voltage, ac-adapter

my Sony Vaio Power Adaptor broke today and i wondering if i could replace the broken one with the Adaptor from my older Vaio, here are the specs :

Broken Adaptor : VGP-AC19V54
Old Adaptor : VGP-AC19V16

Both have an output of 19.5V but the broken one has 7.7A and the old one has 6.2A!

I hope someone here can help me cause i have no idea if this could work!

Thanks a lot

Comment: The broken one is capable of providing **7.7Amps**, and the older one less (**6.2Amps**). It *could* happen that when your equipment i's in need of more power (start-up, reading HD, reading CD /DVD, a lot of USB peripherics), it could blow up your adaptor.

Comment: Take note of all the comments and answers regarding the system drawing more current than what your charger can supply... Ideally I'd go and buy a replacement charger suitable for the device you're powering.

Answer (score 0):

You may experience some instability at high load, but it should be fine.

Make sure that your power connectors are exactly the same, polarity, pin count, shape and size - otherwise you may break your laptop.

If you are not sure swing by a computer shop and they will tell you will it work or not.

Comment: in the worst cases Might discharge the battery instead of charging(It is normal as it can be consuming more amps than it can charge), or cause the charger to overheat and stop working.